# Find a character inside <label> and set class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to highlight some required fields in a form.
I don't have access to the label settings for this application, so I'd like to try finding a character within the label and change it to be more prominent.

The current label for required fields is set as this example:

```
<label>First Name *</label>
```

I would like to find all instances of the asterisk * **within label tags** in a page and wrap them inside a CSS class so I can either set color or replace with an image.
Is that achievable?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

find all labels contain an asterisk,
replace the html with your element

```
 $("label:contains('*')").each(function(){
   var r = $(this).html().replace('*',','<sup class="conditions">*</sup>');
   $(this).html(r);
 });
```

[but this could be done much nicer/faster with css:](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_gen_content.asp)

```
 label.requiredField:after {
    content: "*";
    color:#f00;
 }

 /** your HTML would be **/
 <label class="requiredField">First Name</label>

 /** and renders like: **/
 First Name*
```

more here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html

Comment: I don't have an option to add a class to the labels for required fields, so your first solution is perfect for my scenario. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector will give you want you need:

```
$('label:contains("*")').wrap('<span style="color:red">');
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, doesn't this mean I am finding "labels" containing the asterisk? But I want to find the actual asterisks contained in all labels, so i can assign a class to the asterisks, not to the whole label

Comment: @ale, ah OK, I see. Yes in my answer I wrap the entire label within a span.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(label).filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('*') != -1;
}).each(function () {
    $(this).whatEver();
});
```